# PAD File Submission - Overridden Primary Download URL

Tags: xml, pad-xml

I've submitted my product using PAD 3.11 and shortly after submit (around 60 minutes) another user has updated my software listing with another primary download url and if I resubmit (update) with my own pad xml file again with my original download url, nothing changes.

My question is - how can someone hijack my download url or override my xml and make it impossible for me to update and change back to my original download url for a listing I created myself?

Comment: I'll remove the [pad] tag - maybe we should unlink that from [padding] and use it for [Appvisor's PAD](http://appvisor.com/pad/) instead? I'm going to just suggest a [pad-xml] tag...

Answer (score 0):

That was one of the many weak points of the old PAD Specification. Please make sure to update to PAD v.4, All PAD files are now securely hosted in the Official PAD Repository. It has solved the PAD Forgery and PAD Spam problems. See http://appvisor.com for more info.

Comment: note: asp is a very shady organization installed there mostly to make money not to help independent software developers.